# Visual Studio App Center - VSTS Multiple Organizations

Tags: azure-devops, visual-studio-app-center

I am currently trying to set up a build through Visual Studio App Center to connect to a VSTS repository.

I have a VSTS account through my works Active Directory and I am also a member of other organizations VSTS instances using the same email. When I connect to configure a build through VSTS, I am only given options to projects that I have access to in only my organization.

I have revoked my initial connection per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/connect), but it is still showing only the projects within my organization when re-authorizing.

Is there a way to connect to projects that are a part of the other organizations I am affiliated with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revoke the connection first and then following the steps below:

1. Switch to VSTS Web Portal.
2. Click on Personal Settings and click "My profile".
   [image]
3. Switch to the Directory which contains the VSTS account you want to connect.
   [image]
4. Go back to VSAC and connect to the VSTS. You should see the switched Directory on the OAuth page:
   [image]

Comment: That worked, thank you! I am guessing that if I wanted to create apps/builds for a different organization I would lose any configurations I created for any other organization?